# Highcharts custom data grouping dropped when visible data is changed in navigator

Tags: highcharts

The example [Data grouping by buttons](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/) from the Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons

has a custom data grouping set through the rangeSelector->buttons->dataGrouping

```
    rangeSelector: {
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 3,
            text: 'Day',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['day', [1]]]
            }
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: 'Week',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['week', [1]]]
            }
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'Month',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['month', [1]]]
            }
        }],
    },
```

[image]

Unfortunately the data grouping is dropped when visible data is changed in the navigator (the selected Weekly data grouping is changed to Daily grouping is used)

[image]

The same happens when the date range is changed through the calendar (rangeSelector->input).

Is there a way to keep the data grouping after changing date range in navigator or calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Set in buttons options [buttons.preserveDataGrouping](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.preserveDataGrouping) to true.

When buttons apply dataGrouping on a series, by default zooming in/out will deselect buttons and unset dataGrouping. Enable this option to keeps buttons selected when extremes change.

```
  buttons: [{
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: 'Day',
    preserveDataGrouping: true,
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [
        ['day', [1]]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: 'Week',
    preserveDataGrouping: true,
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [
        ['week', [1]]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'Month',
    preserveDataGrouping: true,
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [
        ['month', [1]]
      ]
    }
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2nm1qtLy/

Comment: thank you. That works. I somehow missed preserveDataGrouping in the api.